# How to make image slider auto scrolling in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Any one give me idea on image slider auto scrolling in windows 8?
Having couple of images i am showing in stackpanel bottom of the page.When page is loading it will auto scroll automatically and repeat the images when it is finished the items.

Comment: What have you tried?  My first thought was ScrollViewer + DispatchTimer that makes calls to ScrolltoHorizontalOffset?

Comment: how to set ScrolltoHorizontalOffset dynamically for sliding the images continuoulsy?whenever last image came need to show repeatly from first image as sliding the images.

Comment: I am setting the ScrolltoHorizontalOffset  dynamically but how to repeat the action when last item reached.I mean need to show continuously the images as sliding .